# How to deploy multiple release branches of same spring boot microservice as different endpoints in same ecs cluster

Tags: git, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have two different release branches for my project and I want to have parallel development possible and deploy as different endpoints in Dev and test environments and want to have these different releases branches deployed one after another to prod, in different iterations. I want to use single Ecs fargate cluster to avoid the cost of maintaining multiple Ecs fargate clusters. Please let me know if this is the best practice. What are the issues I may face by opting single ecs cluster instead of multiple ecs clusters? What are the other options I have?

Comment: This is not the best practice, not even remotely. At least use separate clusters, preferably use separate AWS accounts.

Comment: "I want to use single Ecs fargate cluster to avoid the cost of maintaining multiple Ecs fargate clusters." there is ZERO cost involved in creating an ECS cluster for Fargate deployments. The only cost is the individual tasks that are running in the cluster. So separating them into separate clusters would cost exactly the same as having them in the same cluster.